# Jupyter working directory in Pycharm 2019

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Does Pycharm 2019 have a project-level way to specify the working directory, which will be respected by a "managed" Jupyter server, started within an 'attached' project?

It appears that a managed server always executes in the base directory of the 'master' project, and ignores the base directory of the 'attached' project actually containing the notebook file.

[This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000551684-Jupyter-Notebook-default-working-directory) old support thread suggests using the Run/Debug config, but this does not appear to exist for Notebooks anymore.

Every other example I've found requires hardcoding an `os.chdir` into the notebook, which doesn't strike me as great practice.

Comment: Is this your case? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32934

Answer (score -1):

Per [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000551684/comments/360001189980),

> Since PyCharm 2019.x the new implementation of Jupyter is not using run/debug configurations, so working directory settings have no effect.
>
> I'm testing in PyCharm 2019.3 and behavior seems consistent with native Jupyter web app. While working in PyCharm, the working directory returned by `%pwd` command is always the directory where .ipynb file is opened it.